# Extending Text Outside Table Cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a simple graphic I'm trying to make with a table, but for it to work I need to extend the text beyond the table cell - through something like a negative margin - is this possible? Specifically, the bottom row of the table (0,c,r) should line up with the vertical borders above - currently also slightly to the right of each. The graphic represents a number line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htdp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{Sc m{5cm} m{5cm}}
\cline{2-3} 
$\dfrac{1}{x}$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{O} \\
\cline{2-3} 
0 & \flushright{c} & \flushright{r} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please complete your code with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}... \end{document}` etc. being sure to include any packages required. The code should be compilable by others who want to reproduce the output you've posted. A complete small document is much more useful than mere code fragments.

Comment: You can answer your own question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With package `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htdp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{Sc @{\clap{0}} m{5cm} @{$\mathclap{c}$} m{5cm} @{$\mathclap{r}$}}
\cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\dfrac{1}{x}$} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{O} \\
\cline{2-3} 
&&
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `\clap{text}` is typeset as normal text and that `$\mathclap{\alpha}$` is typeset as inline math. They both create boxes of zero width with entries centered.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it with a graphics package. Still interested if there's a way with tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{fillcolour}{HTML}{eeeeee}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (5,0) -- (5,1);
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,1);
\draw [fill=fillcolour] (0,0) rectangle (5,1); 
\node at (2.5,.5) {F}; 
\node at (7.5,.5) {O}; 
\node at (-0.5,0.5) {$\dfrac{1}{x}$};
\node at (0,-0.5) {0};
\node at (5,-0.5) {c};
\node at (10,-0.5) {r};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   %% showframe just for demo
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\noindent\arrayrulewidth1pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.05\hsize}XXX}
\cline{2-3}
\noalign{\vspace{\arrayrulewidth}}
\raggedleft$\dfrac{1}{x}$ &  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{gray!30} F} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{O} \\ \cline{2-3}
\noalign{\vspace{2ex}}
\makebox[\dimexpr\hsize+1.5\tabcolsep][r]{0} & \makebox[\dimexpr\hsize+1.5\tabcolsep][r]{c} & \makebox[\dimexpr\hsize+1.5\tabcolsep][r]{r}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to place `0`, `c` and `r` at their places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{5cm}w{c}{5cm}}[first-col,hvlines]
$\frac{1}{x}$ & F & O \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (2-|1) [below] { \small $0$ } ;
  \node at (2-|2) [below] { \small $\strut c$ } ;
  \node at (2-|3) [below] { \small $\strut r$ } ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]